# Словосочетание идти в ущерб

Tags: перевод

I'm a little confused on this phrase. Are the cases nominative + идти в ущерб + dative? Спасибо

Comment: Note, that the correct Russian word is "фраза".

Comment: @YellowSky - phrase is not the same as фраза.  The word "phrase" is a false friend.

Comment: @user31264 - There's **no** such Russian word as "фраз". The noun "фраза" in the Genitive plural is "фраз", still, it's a form of "фраза" meaning "of the phrases" like in "значение этих фраз" - 'the meaning of these phrases.'

Comment: Aleks - "идти в ущерб" is not a фраза, but словосочетание.  There is no word "фраз" in Russian, and фраза means sentence (in the context of language, there is also "музыкальная фраза".

Comment: I know (and just wrote it) that there's no such Russian word as "фраз", but you cannot say that "фраза" is **the** correct Russian word.  It is only **a** correct Russian word, and "the" correct word is probably словосочетание.

Comment: @user31264 , a list in increasing order of length — `словосочетание, сочетание слов, сочетание предложений (сложное синтаксическое целое или сверхфразовое единство)`. I suppose it is a `сочетание слов`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. Usually it is used as:

```
X не должен (не может, не будет) идти в ущерб Y.
```

X is in nominative, Y is in dative. The verb `должен` (`может`, `будет`) matches the gender and number of X.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is:

> Х *(именительный падеж, кто? что?)* идёт в ущерб Y *(дательный падеж, кому? чему?)*.

Example:

> Излишний контроль *(что?)* идёт в ущерб развитию *(чему?)*.

*(Excessive control comes at the expense of development.)*

Of course, don't forgot to put the verb `идти` and the noun `развитие` in the correct form, according to the gender and number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. In addition, I'd say there might be some limitations for what is used as the subject in the place before the "не должно идти в ущерб" expression. Typically, the subject tends to mean some continuing action (like doing something) or occupation (like a hobby) rather than some static object or thing. For example, "не должно идти в ущерб" can be used in a situation like this:

Your hobby shouldn't get in the way of your working on PhD.

Твоё хобби не должно идти в ущерб работе над диссертацией.

Synonyms for "идти в ущерб":

- вредить,
- идти во вред,
- мешать 
  (чему либо).